# Switch to Error View OnException

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to redirect to other view on Exception. I have the following code OnException. But how can I change the view?

```
     protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
     {    // Let other exceptions just go unhandled    
           if (filterContext.Exception is InvalidOperationException) 
           {        // Switch to an error view        ...    
           }
     }
```

How to switch to an error view??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok..managed to do this using following code:

```
         var controllerName = (string)filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"]; 
         var actionName = (string)filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"]; 
         var model = new HandleErrorInfo(filterContext.Exception, controllerName,actionName); 
         filterContext.Result = new ViewResult 
         {             
            ViewName = View,
            MasterName = Master,
            ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary<HandleErrorInfo>(model),  
            TempData = filterContext.Controller.TempData      
        };
```